# Stop Clicking through Layer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one layer as a background and another layer (icon) sitting on the background layer, both have different functionality.

When I click on the icon, the icon's function works and it works through the background layer, too.  This is not expected!
How to get the click works on only the icon, not going though the background layer?  Thanks.

[LIVE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/p8snuxfc/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="redBG">
    <div class="yellowIcon"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.redBG{
    background-color:red;
    width: 300px;
    height:30px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.grayBG{
    background-color: gray;
}

.yellowIcon{
    background-color:yellow;
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index:20;
}
.greenBG{background-color:green}
```

JS

```
$('.redBG').click(
    function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('grayBG');
    });

$('.yellowIcon').click(
    function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('greenBG');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stopPropagation()` like this:

```js
$('.redBG').click(

function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('grayBG');
});

$('.yellowIcon').click(

function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('greenBG');
});
```

```css
.redBG {
    background-color:red;
    width: 300px;
    height:30px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.grayBG {
    background-color: gray;
}
.yellowIcon {
    background-color:yellow;
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index:20;
}
.greenBG {
    background-color:green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="redBG">
    <div class="yellowIcon"></div>
</div>
```

`event.stopPropagation()` prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.
For reference: http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

For the question in the comment to explain the `e` in this function: if you check the provided link to the jQuery API you'll notice that there it's written as follows for the example provided:

```
$( "p" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Do something
});
```

Note that it's not necessary to explicitly write `function(event)` - the parameter of the function in this notation *is* the `click()` event. Many people just tend to shorten `event` with `e` as the `stopPropation()` is just called upon the event that is the parameter of the `function()` called in `click(function(){});`.

For illustration I've just added the console log message `console.log(e);` in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wh3mLvbk/) for the `click()` event. When you click on the `.yellowIcon`, you'll notice the console message

```
Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", ....}
```

So `e` is just the passed `click()` event object.
If you change the `click()` to e.g. `hover()`, the console message is

```
Object { originalEvent=Event mouseover, type="mouseenter", ...}
Object { originalEvent=Event mouseover, type="mouseleave", ...}
```

For further and more detailed information you can check http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: Thank you, Matthias very much for your help!  It works as expected.  Can you please explain the `e` in this function?  Thanks.

Comment: @abcidd Glad I was able to help you. I've just updated my answer with an explanation for the `e` in the function as it would be too long to post it as comment.

Comment: Thank you very much, Matthias!  Your explanation is very clear and direct.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `$('.yellowIcon').click()` function:

```
$('.yellowIcon').click(
    function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).toggleClass('greenBG');
    }
);
```